# What is the difference between onComplete and foreach for a future in Scala?

Tags: scala, foreach, concurrency, future

I wonder the difference between onComplete and foreach when we use a Future in Scala.

`f onComplete (_ => doSomething(_))`

and

`f foreach (_ => doSomething(_))`

1. Do the above lines of code lead to the same result?
2. If I want to doSomething with Future f only after it's completed. What should I do? Should I use isCompleted like this:

   `if(f.isCompleted) f onComplete (_ => doSomething(_))`

Thank you guys a lot

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The main difference is the `onComplete` callback gets called even if the future completes with a *failure*, while `foreach` (and `onSuccess`) functions are called only in case of a *successful* result.

In fact, `onComplete`'s parameter is a function `Try[T] => U`: the function you pass will be called with a `Success[T]` as argument if the future is successful or with a `Failure` if there was an exception:

```
val f = Future { ??? } // this future completes with a failure

// foreach only calls the callback if the future is successful
f.foreach(_ => thisWillNeverExecute()) 

// This will print "future failed" after the future completes
f.onComplete {
  case Success(_) => println("future completed successfully")
  case Failure(e) => println("future failed")
}
```

Also, you don't need to check anything to call the mentioned methods: `onComplete`/`onSuccess`/`onFailure`/`foreach` all schedule a callback that is called on the implicit `ExecutionContext` you have in scope, only when the future completes.

You can call them even if `isCompleted` is false, they will only be executed when the future completes successfully or fails, depending on which one you chose.

Let's have a look at their signatures:

```
def onComplete[U](@f: Try[T] => U)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit
```

- `onComplete` takes a `Try[T] => U` function: this function will be executed on the `implicit executor` when the future completes. The argument will either be a `Success[T]` if the future is successful or a `Failure` if the future is failed

---

```
def onFailure[U](pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, U])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit
```

- `onFailure` parameter is a `PartialFunction` that is only executed on the `implicit executor` if the future fails with a `Throwable` for which `pf` is defined. It's basically the same as calling onComplete matching only some `Failure`s, and in fact that is exactly how it is implemented in the standard library.

---

```
def onSuccess[U](pf: PartialFunction[T, U])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit
```

- `onSuccess` parameter is, symmetrically to `onFailure`, a `PartialFunction` that is only executed on the `implicit executor` if the future completes successfully and the supplied `PartialFunction` is defined for the value.

---

```
def foreach[U](f: T => U)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit
```

- `foreach` is basically the same as `onSuccess` but it takes a total function. This means that `f` is always executed if the Future completes successfully

---

N.B.:
'onSuccess' and 'onFailure' are going to be deprecated in 2.12. I suggest you read [this series of posts by Viktor Klang](https://github.com/viktorklang/blog/blob/master/Futures-in-Scala-2.12-part-5.md) to find out how you will be affected by the changes

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very detailed. I learnt a lot from that. So, it means that `foreach` is equivalent to `onSuccess`. Is that right?

Comment: `foreach` is a "total" version of `onSuccess`. if you pass a total function to `onSuccess` they are virtually equivalent.
 Both `foreach` and `onSuccess` are implemented in terms of `onComplete`, but that's gonna change in 2.12